# Add allowed methods to urls for rest_framework_bulk

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

So this is the first time I use `djangorestframework-bulk` for implementing batch requests. If I understand correctly, you should be able get this functionality out-of-the-box by just having your `*ViewSet` classes inherit also from the app's mixins like `BulkUpdateModelMixin` or viewsets like `BulkUpdateAPIView`.

As stated on [the notes in the repo](http://git.io/pF7QRw):

> Most API urls have two URL levels for each resource:
>
> ```
> url(r'foo/', ...)
> url(r'foo/(?P<pk>\d+)/', ...)
> ```
>
> The second url however is not applicable for bulk operations because
>   the url directly maps to a single resource. Therefore all bulk generic
>   views only apply to the first url.

However, when I try to perform `PUT` or `PATCH` bulk requests (haven't tried with `DELETE`) to an endpoint in my app, like:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/users/
```

I get the following error:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/users/ 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)
```

Is there any additional configuration I need to do in order for this url to allow PUT and PATCH requests and have my viewset's `update()` and `partial_update()` process such requests?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've implemented the `bulk` methods through the `BulkUpdateModelMixin`, but you don't have a proper router for your `ViewSet`. You now need, for example, `put` to go to `bulk_update` rather than just `update`.

Check out [here](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/issues/11) for an example of how to set up your own router to allow for bulk update functionality with DRF `ViewSets`. Basically, map out the verbs to call the proper method.